# How can I force my typescript (.eslintrc) project to validate that my .tsx files have the PascalCase mode?

Tags: typescript

I'm new with this `eslintrc` stuff, and I want to know how I can make my files with `.tsx` or `.jsx` extensions be forced to be called in `PascalCase` format.

For example, I get this file in my project: `src/pages/my_component.tsx`.

I need `MyComponent.tsx` insted of `my_component.tsx`

How can I do this?

This is the content of my file `.eslintrc.js`

```
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true,
    },
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'prettier', 'json', 'jest'],
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:prettier/recommended',
        'plugin:jest/recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    ],
    rules: {
        'linebreak-style': ['error', 'unix'],
        quotes: ['error', 'single'],
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'eslint-plugin-unicorn/filename-case': https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/filename-case.md

## Example

```
"unicorn/filename-case": [
    "error",
    {
        "case": "pascalCase"
    }
]
```

Comment: thanks!  Should I put this piece of code in my .eslint after of install this package? how can config PascalCase for my .tsx and .jsx files?